# Clicking on the first option js

Tags: javascript, html

Tell me please, there is a code in which when you click option select, a div element is added with an option value.
But there is a problem, which is that you cannot immediately click on the first option, you must first click on the second, and only after the first. How to fix this problem?
Thank you in advance.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"><input name="my_input"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Because you event is bind to `onchange` of the select. By default 1 is selected to there is way to change that 1 again. Keep a default value like "Select a number" something like that and then when you change it to 1 it will works like other numbers.

Comment: @DeepakBiswal Thank you very much, I will do as you advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html dropdown you can not able to select a value which already selected, so must need to add one more option in your dropdown which say "Please Select" and after that you can able to select any option. That's the right solution

See working example:-

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  if(!new_input.value) return false;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"><input name="my_input"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you done it with onchange event so the first option is already selected thats why first time it doesn't add div so for overcome that just add one more option to html like

```
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="">select Option</option> 
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

and put condition in javascript like,

```
if(document.getElementById("selector").value != ""){
    //add your div here
}
```

this condition must apply because when you select first option it did not be added like select options.